# cakephp post data field missing from SQL update statement

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Having trouble geting cakephp to update a record.

Controller Code:

```
public function viewBenefit($id) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->set('post', $this->request->data);
        $this->Benefit->id = $id;
        if ($this->Benefit->save($this->Benefit->data)) {
            $myVars['Sucsess'] = TRUE;
            $this->Session->setFlash('Updates Saved');
        } else {
            $myVars['NewID'] = 0;
            $myVars['Sucsess'] = False;
            $this->Session->setFlash('There was an error.');
        }
    }

    $this->Benefit->recursive = 2;
    $this->Benefit->id = $id;
    $this->set('benefit', $this->Benefit->read());
}
```

Relevant View Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Benefit',array('action'=>'edit','url' => '#')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type'=>'hidden')) . "\n"; ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('short_description',array('type'=>'textarea')) . "\n"; ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

NOTE: The Form is sumbitted via JS

POST Data (via debug($post); )

```
array(
    'Benefit' => array(
        'id' => '1952e98e-f589-47d4-b458-11a1bd58ba3b',
        'short_description' => '<p>This is great sample insurance 321321</p>'
    )
)
```

SQL UPDATE statment:

```
UPDATE `c16memberdev`.`benefits` SET `modified` = '2012-12-04 10:45:16' WHERE `c16memberdev`.`benefits`.`id` = '1952e98e-f589-47d4-b458-11a1bd58ba3b'
```

As you can see the field "short_description" does not get added to the SQL statement, and therefore the data not added to the database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is $this->Benefit->data getting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$this->Benefit->save($this->Benefit->data)
```

to

```
$this->Benefit->save($this->request->data)
```